# Hide a div by data-role attribute with CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have searched for this answer to no avail. If a div exists as such:
`div[data-role="form-footer"]`

What is the best way to hide this , and is it possible by CSS?

I have attempted to use, to no avail (I believe because the form div is being inserted through a script):

```
#form div[data-role="form-footer"] {
   display: none !important;
}
```

The data-roll appears on the web version of the site only. In the code, it is inserted through script tags

Comment: Is there an ancestor element with id="form" or do you perhaps mean form div[data-role="form-footer" Have a look in your browser's inpector to see what HTML structure you have around there and also what inherited CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough "reputation" to comment.
Yes it is possible with CSS
Just use

```css
display:none;
```

To hide any element.
Example:-

```
div[data-role="form-footer"]{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, however because the div is being inserted by a script; this is not working

Comment: You haven't mentioned that in your question , make sure to put all the necessary code and information in your question. Even though if it is being inserted by script it should work.

Comment: can you provide the whole code including HTML and JS. So that we can understand easily.

Comment: The data-roll appears on the web version of the site only. In the code, it is inserted through script tags

Comment: It doesn't matter how it is inserted. If the css matches it affects the element. Maybe some other css overwrites your display none?

Comment: Shouldn't be possible if I use the !important tag correct?